# What is the top limit for torque per diameter ratio for electrical rotation mechanism working in a tube?

Tags: motors, gears, torque

Use case: industrial stop valve placed in an another pipe welded perpendicularly making a T-shape.

To make the question more specific let's consider 50mm inner diameter pipe for the linear actuator inside with electric motor and some gear drive (most probably needed).
The achieved torque should be continuously sustainable through the life-time of 20,000 hours. Rotation speed and power are of secondary importance while length should be reasonable, let's say: 1000mm.

I considered planetary, cycloidal, harmonic drives, magnetic gears and various direct drive motors with an option to stack them on the same shaft. The top value I found is achievable with electric motor and planetary gearbox: ~40Nm.

Can it be significantly higher, say 100Nm and what is the limit?

Comment: And the outer diameter? If the wall thickness is sufficient it will support a massive load...

Comment: @solar-mike, yes, wall thickness is enough to balance rotation force an push force of the actuator